# How to add this constraint to a problem using python-constraint

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, constraint-programming

I am trying to use python-constraint to solve a combinatorial problem but I can't seem to add the constraint I need to the problem. My problem is that I have 9 square tiles that have to be placed and each tile can be rotated to one of 4 positions, I've encoded the tiles as vectors and need particular pairs of elements to add to zero.

Using an example with two tiles:

`piece_1 = np.array([-1,-3, 4, 2])`

`piece_2 = np.array([-2, -1, 3, 2])`

Each vector can be rolled to form a set of 4 vectors for each:

`piece_1_set = [np.roll(piece_1, i) for i in range(4)]`

`piece_2_set = [np.roll(piece_2, i) for i in range(4)]`

I've added them to the problem with:

`problem.addVariable("1", piece_1_set)`

`problem.addVariable("2", piece_2_set)`

What I'd like to do is find a vector from each set such that the 2nd element from the first vector and the 4th element from the second vector sum to 0.

I've tried all kinds of versions of:

`problem.addConstraint(lambda i,j: i[1] + j[3] == 0, ("1", "2"))`

`problem.addConstraint(lambda i,j: np.any(i[1]) + np.any(j[3]) == 0, ("1", "2"))`

But I always return the following:

`ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`

Does anyone know how to phrase this constraint such that I can add them to get the solutions to the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be just that you are trying to use numpy arrays with the python-constraint library rather than inbuilt python lists. You need to convert them back as in the solution below.

```
import numpy as np
from constraint import *

problem = Problem()

piece_1 = np.array([-1,-3, 4, 2])
piece_2 = np.array([-2, -1, 3, 2])
piece_1_set = [list(np.roll(piece_1, i)) for i in range(4)]
piece_2_set = [list(np.roll(piece_2, i)) for i in range(4)]

problem.addVariable("1", piece_1_set)
problem.addVariable("2", piece_2_set)

problem.addConstraint(lambda i, j: i[0] == j[0], ("1", "2"))
problem.getSolutions()
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you for this, I hadn't considered that!